# Angular search filter text from API not working

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I need to filter values which are coming from API. I tried this way. But I'm getting `ERROR TypeError: items.filter is not a function` Could you please help me to solve this issue.

HTML

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-3">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button id="btncat-search" class="btn btn-primary p-3" type="button">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>

        <div *ngFor="let cat of categories, let i=index"  [ngClass]="((i % 2)==0) ? 'col-md-5 left-col':'col-md-4'">
          <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn">{{cat.name | filter : searchText}}</button>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PIPE.TS

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
        if(!items) return [];
        if(!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter( it => {
          return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
        });
       }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a filter pipe! https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: console.log your `items` in PIPE, it won't be an array that's why this error. Also follow the suggestion by @bambam, If you would want the pipe to work, you will have to make your pipe as `@Pipe({
    name: 'filter', pure: false
})`, but then this will run on every change detection, if your array is large it will cause unnecessary performance issues.

Comment: What is the best way to do the filtering?

Comment: Just read the paragraph I linked to, it’s carefully explained there.